# Isotope JS with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to include the .js plugin, Isotope into my wordpress install, at the bottom of the page here:http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net/test-2/

Im using this example over at codepen: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mEinp

I have enqueued the script from a CDN like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', 'https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js');
```

I can include my whole enqueue file if it helps?

Here's the template HTML im trying (I have placed the initialisation script at the bottom for now but will move it to its own .js file):

```
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 100
  }
});

</script>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.grid-item--width2 { width: 200px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
```

The CSS and HTML seem fine - I just don't know if m enquiring it properly or the initialisation .js is correct as it seems to work but its just not sorting as per the codepen.

Comment: i would put the isotope firing call into a js file and enqueue that after the isotope.js call. Should work fine then. Currently you're using the vanilla js to fire isotope, not the jQuery document load version as you have here in your example. That means isotope is not launching on your site on an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the URL that you gave and found this in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Looking at this, I would replace it like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.grid').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 100
      }
    });
});
```

And that should solve your problem.